# Currently stuck getting The Differential Cross Section to work

Tags: equations, amsmath

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
\centering
$\frac{d^2\sigma}{{d\Omega}{d\omega}}$ = $f( Q, \omega )$
\caption{}
\end{equation}
```

But this results in the (1.2) tag being underneath the equation, not to the side as I would like. I'm having a great deal of problems with writing the differential section.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use neither `\centering` nor `\caption{}`. The equations are automatically centered and numbered.

Your code needed a bit of cleanup, e.g. the `$` in math environment, which you won't need and don't have to use

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\frac{d^2\sigma}{d\Omega d\omega}=f(Q,\omega)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

A bit more text around to see how it is centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\frac{d^2\sigma}{d\Omega d\omega}=f(Q,\omega)
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]

**EDIT**

I corrected the code as suggested, not leaving the space before the `equation` environment as suggested by @barbarabeeton, in order to have the correct spacing and not to allow page breaks.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. I see my error as well.

Comment: oh, *don't* leave a blank line before `equation` -- it fouls up the vertical spacing, and allows a page break before the display.